# Let $A$ be an infinite set. Then there exists bijection from $A$ to $A\times A$

Tags: set-theory

I am looking through the proof in Hungerford's book. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I understand almost all of the proof, but the part that confuses me is at the end, where he says that the existence of a bijection $\left(B\cup C\right)\times\left(B\cup C\right)\rightarrow B\cup C$ would contradict the maximality of $g$. But the partial order is defined by extension, so we not only have to find a bijection  $\left(B\cup C\right)\times\left(B\cup C\right)\rightarrow B\cup C$, we would have to show that it extends $g$ as well. I am assuming that it is indeed possible to find such a bijection, but I have not been able to deduce this from Hungerford's reasoning in this proof.

Comment: That was only a sketch, with the details left for you to fill in. Extend $g$ with a bijection from $C \times B \cup B\times C \cup C\times C$ to $C$ (you already showed that the cardinalities work OK for this). Good question though, it shows you were paying attention!

Comment: I think it would be better if he partially ordered, by inclusion, the subsets $X$ of $A$ for which there exists a bijection $f:X\times X\to X.$ Nothing in the last paragraph mentions any specific function.  Good Q.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Show that $g$ can be embedded in mapping in $(B\cup C)\times (B\cup C)\rightarrow(B\cup C)$, and $g$ can not be maximal in it.